# What are the main steps to develop a GSM VoIP service?

Tags: architecture, voip, gsm, telecommunication

This isn't a programming/technical question, but a architectural one.

Currently, I work in a telecommunication services company, and I'd like to know how does the VoIP (Skype, Viber, and so on...) services work and what are the steps to implement them. To develop a VoIP system, what is the architectural design, which technologies should be used, and what are the bureaucratical issues?

**My objective: create a service that allows GSM users to make free phone calls (using Wi-Fi or 3G/4G).**

Thanks in advance. And sorry for the broadness.

Comment: Read about SIP. Have a look at Asterisk.

Comment: Thank you Bernd. I'll take a read! =]